# How to fix resource not found in react native android

Tags: android, react-native

So i have the following error:

```
error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
```

and the file itself looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat" parent="Base.V28.Theme.AppCompat"/>
    <style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light" parent="Base.V28.Theme.AppCompat.Light"/>
    <style name="Base.V28.Theme.AppCompat" parent="Base.V26.Theme.AppCompat">
        <!-- We can use the platform styles on API 28+ -->
        <item name="dialogCornerRadius">?android:attr/dialogCornerRadius</item>
    </style>
    <style name="Base.V28.Theme.AppCompat.Light" parent="Base.V26.Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- We can use the platform styles on API 28+ -->
        <item name="dialogCornerRadius">?android:attr/dialogCornerRadius</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

This is a 3rd party library and i wonder if this is some kind of configuration opened by the 3rd party library to let me configure the library variables. But i have no idea on how to configure this, im using react native `0.60.5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem with react-native-navigation. what I did to fix my problem was just update react-native-navigation's compileSdkVersion,targetSdkVersion,buildToolsVersion in its build.gradle to same version as mine and the problem was solved.

**But note, if you run npm i or yarn or even install a new library in your project you may have to do it again.**

hope this helps.

Comment: Seriously? I have been thinking that this is also the case but i dont know if this is the only way

Comment: btw it works, but i dont like the approach, but i know last time i have no choice but to do this. gimme some time if nobody give a better answer, i will consider this as the best answer

Comment: It's good to hear that it works, if you need an alternative you should really consider opening an issue on the third party plugin's GitHub page. The creator or collaborators may be able to fix the issue in the next release.

Comment: yeah man! you saved my days when it's near to release day of my project. i already raise the issue: https://github.com/zaguiini/react-native-pure-jwt/issues/13. maybe just wait for them to handle this. bad news is that the library seems to be not maintained that much

Comment: ok nobody has any better solution, so i will mark this as the solution as per 2nd october 2019